# uuid_msgs on Raspberry pi

Tags: ros, raspberrypi, rocon, rasbperrypi, jessie

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to install uuid_msgs on Raspberry pi Jessie？

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242600/uuid_msgs-on-raspberry-pi/) by [Steven.Zhang](https://answers.ros.org/users/27851/steven.zhang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-08-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-08-29**:
The same way you would install any other released package. What ROS distro are you using? Where did you get it?

**Comment by [Steven.Zhang](https://answers.ros.org/users/27851/steven.zhang/) on 2016-08-29**:
The indigo,http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the section titled [Adding Released Packages](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi#Adding_Released_Packages), include `uuid_msgs` in the `rosinstall_generator` command, along with any other released packages you use:

```
$ rosinstall_generator uuid_msgs ros_comm ros_control joystick_drivers --rosdistro indigo --deps --wet-only --exclude roslisp --tar > indigo-custom_ros.rosinstall
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1